# Trying to get the index of an array of images when clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

```js
function openGallery(){
    console.log($(this).index()); 
}

$("body").on( "click", "#gallery img", openGallery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="grid-x grid-padding-x section-content" id="gallery">
<div class="cell small-12">
 <h1>Gallery</h1>
</div>

<div class="cell small-12">
 <section class="grid-x grid-padding-x small-up-2 medium-up-4 large-up-6">
<div class="cell"><img src="img/gallery/gallery-1-sm.jpg" alt="gallery 1"></div>
<div class="cell"><img src="img/gallery/gallery-2-sm.jpg" alt="gallery 2"></div>
<div class="cell"><img src="img/gallery/gallery-3-sm.jpg" alt="gallery 3"></div>
<div class="cell"><img src="img/gallery/gallery-4-sm.jpg" alt="gallery 4"></div>
<div class="cell"><img src="img/gallery/gallery-5-sm.jpg" alt="gallery 5"></div>
<div class="cell"><img src="img/gallery/gallery-6-sm.jpg" alt="gallery 6"></div>
</section> 
</div>
</section>
```

// I keep getting 0 as the index valley of what is clicked on. I think I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: You could use data-attributes like "data-index=1, 2, 3" on your images and $(this).data("index");

Comment: and how would I then check for the attribute?

Comment: All the img tags are index zero of their parent <div> tags.

Comment: @icekomo i edited my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swap `$(this).index()` for `$(this).index('img')`

For more information about using the `jQuery` `.index()` function [**Click Here**](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

```js
function openGallery() {
  console.log($(this).index('img'));
}

$(document).on("click", "#gallery img", openGallery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="gallery">
  <div class="cell"><img src="img/gallery/gallery-1-sm.jpg" alt="gallery 1"></div>
  <div class="cell"><img src="img/gallery/gallery-2-sm.jpg" alt="gallery 2"></div>
  <div class="cell"><img src="img/gallery/gallery-1-sm.jpg" alt="gallery 1"></div>
  <div class="cell"><img src="img/gallery/gallery-1-sm.jpg" alt="gallery 1"></div>
  <div class="cell"><img src="img/gallery/gallery-1-sm.jpg" alt="gallery 1"></div>
  <div class="cell"><img src="img/gallery/gallery-1-sm.jpg" alt="gallery 1"></div>
</section>
```

If you have any questions please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: What would cause the console log to come back with an index of 5 for the first image instead of 0?

Comment: @icekomo it shouldn't as you can see from my example unless you have other images within the section tag with the `id` of `gallery`. If you can give an example - reproduce the issue for me to see then I might be able to help with that issue.

Comment: I updated the html to show you exactly what I have. The JS is the same as what you have, but for some reason it's throwing me back an index value starting at 4.

Comment: Without seeing it I cannot try find the problem. please create a JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ to reproduce the problem and I will see if I can find the reason behind it and fix that for you

Comment: it seems because I'm using document in the click call it's registering all img tags.  $(document).on("click", "#gallery img", openGallery);

Comment: how do I make a snippet like that rather than just showing the code itself? @NewToJS

Comment: @turmuka when text editor to write your answer/solution has icons in the toolbar, look for the paper with <> in the middle.

Comment: works now on my last answer, have been trying to figure that out for last 2 days, thanks @NewToJS

Answer (score 0):

Each image is in its own div, so each has a sibling list with just one element (itself), which is why the index is always zero. This would work:

```
function openGallery(){
    console.log($(this).parent().index()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always zero because there is only 1 `<img>` in each cell which is obviously all of them are index zeroes. If you want the index better put the click event listener on `.cell` instead or you can put unique `id` in each `<img>` tags.